# How can I study Linux, in and out?

Tags: linux, security

My team and I will soon begin studying and practicing for the nation-wide Cyber Patriot program. As I'm famed for being our "Linux guy", I would really like to improve my knowledge on the subject. Does anyone have any recommendations as to where to start? Generally with an emphasis on securing Linux machines. I have a machine running linux, but I don't know the ins and outs of the OS.

Comment: https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/browse/index.cfm?category=benchmarks.os.linux

Comment: @cremefraiche Cyber Patriot is a competition that you win through knowledge of the linux operating system, not diagnostic tools.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what a security benchmark is. Try opening the relevant document before denouncing it without even knowing the information it contains. You won't make it very far not knowing to mount `/var` `/var/log` `/var/log/audit`  `/var/tmp` `/home` `/` individually, and knowing which flags to set on the partitions, or even which partitions to bind mount.

Comment: I'm sorry for censuring your PDF. It's actually exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I know it is, that's why I persisted. I admit, I should have given you more info to go off of from the beginning. I recommend bookmarking the site, I struggle to remember where to find it every time.

Comment: I've just saved the PDF. I'll probably print it eventually, but until then I'll study it on my tablet. Thank you very much.

Comment: @cremefraiche These documents are indeed interesting - it's worth posting an answer!

Answer (score 2):

What I always recommend to people (and few seem to like it) is don't. Don't go to a "structured" Linux learning program. Everyone that I have seen has been at best an in depth walk though on how to do a thing one way. What you should try to do instead is appearance with people that do something near what your doing. Try a local LUG (Linux user group). Or volunteer in an IT department at a charity or non-profit. Basically favor real experience over structured learning.

That said, it's handy to keep a couple sites or references that you can refer to all the time.

Try and find a project where you can participate in a "junior" role, and learn from that. You will end up with much more usable knowledge  and experience then any course or reading material can provide.